# Decentralize substrate template

Tags: substrate-node-template, validator, aura

In the substrate node template only alice and bob is validator who can auth block but i want to let any account to be able to validate and block how do i do it so any one can create block and finilaze?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this Substrate Tutorial: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/add-trusted-nodes/

It shows you how the validator that wants to join your node can to generate their keys, how to modify the chain specification to add those key pairs.

Comment: Sorry i have edited the question my question was how to let anyone to register in the authority pallet so he can be able to create or finish block